# SQL Server - Comparação por período mensal

Tags: sql-server

Olá, pessoal. tenho uma grande dúvida.

Tenho dois bancos (MySQL) onde acumulo vendas de varias lojas e uso um terceiro banco onde faço um ETL usando o pentaho para união dos dados.

Em meu terceiro banco (SQL Server) preciso criar uma query que faça uma comparação por período mensal e indique se um cliente é INATIVO ou ATIVO.

**Exemplos**

**Condição 1:** Se um determinado cliente fizer compras em uma determinada loja que nos acumulados o valor seja **>= R$230,00** no mês de janeiro de 2018, ele recebe o status de **“ATIVO”** e **“VENDA DIRETA**” naquele período.

**Condição 2:** Se o mesmo cliente da condição 1 fizer compras na mesma loja no mês de março de 2018 e nos acumulados o valor seja **< R$230,00**, ele recebe o status de **“INATIVO”** e não recebe o status de **“VENDA DIRETA”** naquele período.

**Estrutura da tabela para exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo a Maria Aparecida ganhou o status de **ATIVA** no mês de janeiro e **INATIVA** no mês de março por não ter atingido o valor minimo de R$230,00 mensal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT q.*, CASE WHEN /*q.mes = 1 AND*/ q.valor >= 230.0                  THEN 'ATIVO'
                 WHEN /*q.mes = 3 AND*/ q.valor < 230.0 AND q.n_lojas = 1 THEN 'INATIVO'
                 ELSE '-' END as status
FROM (
    SELECT nome, MONTH(dt_compra) as mes, YEAR(dt_compra) as ano, 
           SUM(valor) as valor, COUNT(DISTINCT loja_cnpj)) as n_lojas
    FROM tabela
    GROUP BY nome, MONTH(dt_compra), YEAR(dt_compra)) as q
ORDER BY q.nome, q.ano, q.mes
```